# What does it mean if a using directive is light blue in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using-directives

This is the code. I've tried rewriting it in a new program but it's the same problem as soon as I create a class the "using system" and the others appear in light blue as well as attributes.

[image: class Book[][1]]

[image: class program]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you can remove them from the file. Visual Studio includes some `using` directives automatically when you create a class, because they're so frequently used.

For instance,

- the `System` library includes types like `String`, `Int32`, `DateTime`, tons of exceptions like `IndexOutOfRangeException`, `FormatException`, etc.
- the `System.Collections.Generic` library includes `List<T>`, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, etc, and nearly every program will use a collection of some sort.
- the `System.Linq` library is self-explanatory; again, nearly every program will use LINQ.

But if you don't use anything in them, Visual Studio greys them out so you know they're unused.

If you don't need them, you can delete them.

Comment: but i am using the attributes why are they grayed out

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, this problem has been bugging for 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Using in light blue are not used in the file.

Example of use of `class Task` in `System.Threading.Tasks`:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Example
{
   ...
   private void ExampleFunc()
   {
       // Whitout using
       System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000).Wait();

       // OR

       // With using
       Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
   }
   ...
}
```

You have to read the documentation to learn how to use class inside packages. And the most important for begining, what package is made for.

Comment: how can i use them ?

Comment: When you use a class or something else in an assembly, otherwise you can delete them